# Azure Form recognizer V3: create, read custom model projects with sdk or rest api

Tags: azure, azure-form-recognizer

We are using Azure Form Recognizer to extract invoice data from our suppliers. Each supplier has some custom fields we would like to extract.
We would like to train a custom model for each supplier.
I am trying to automaticly create a new project for each new supplier. Currently the only way I have found to do this, is with form recognizer studio.

[image: Create new project with form recognizer studio]

**Is it possible to do this through a Rest API or SDK?**

With V2 the projects data was stored in a json file in blobstorage and could be mutated.

Comment: Yes, Its possible to train custom model of Form recognizer by using API, refer here -https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/applied-ai-services/form-recognizer/how-to-guides/includes/v2-1/rest-api.md#train-a-custom-model and for sdk refer here - https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/applied-ai-services/form-recognizer/how-to-guides/compose-custom-models.md